# Mongodb Deep Embedded Object Array Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

Hi I am facing a problem in updating an embedded object array using mongoose!

Here is the Schema:

```
var event = {
    eTime : [String]
};

var schedule = {
    events: [event]
};

var group = {
    gName: {type:String},
    sDate:  { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    schedules: [schedule]
}; 

MainSchema {
    id          :   String,
    groups      :   [group]
};
```

The thing which I want to do is that to update the array of `eTime` in events with an object of schedules. I am using this query

```
db.demoDb.update({
   'id': 'MongoDb', 
   'groups':{
       $elemMatch:{
           'gName':'noSql'
       }
    }
 },
 {
    $push:{
      'groups':{
          'schedules':{
              'events':{
                   'eTime':'01-Marach-15'
               }
           }
       }
    }
  }
)
```

but the schedules->events->eventTime is not updating with a value!!!

What wrong I am doing here?

My Main Scenario is to find the id(MongoDB) with associated gName and then update its schedules array of it.

My find query is working great but can not update the schedules... and events can be many

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your schema correctly, the core part is an array containing an array containing an array containing an array of strings. I think you would do much better "inverting" the schema so each document represents an event. Metadata grouping multiple events can be duplicated into each event document. An example:

```
{
    "event" : "cookie bake-off",
    "gName" : "baking",
    "sDate" : ISODate("2015-03-02T21:46:11.842Z")
}
```

The update that you are struggling with translates into an insertion of a new event document in the collection.